# Laravel 5 Package Development GIT setup

Tags: php, git, laravel

I have some great code I want to share....so I am moving code from my laravel 5 app into individual packages for use through composer/packagist.

This will also allow me to separate out code I only want in development and avoid deployment of nasty database modification classes to production.

I am confused on setting up git. My main project is running on a git repository. I am developing the packages under a sub-folder named packages/myname/package_name1/ . Each package is going to want its own git repository.

Should I add the folder "packages" to my .gitignore file for my main repository, then set up a git repository for each subfolder?

I followed this tutorial: [Setup Laravel 5 Package](https://github.com/jaiwalker/setup-laravel5-package)

Comment: Check out git `submodules`. [Everything you need is right here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using composer/packagist then yes, you should add the folder packages to .gitignore on your main repository. When deploying the entire application or when updating a package you'll have to do a `composer install/update` to keep everything up to date.